# Ruby Thor Script through Symlink want calling directory

Tags: ruby, middleman, thor

I want to get the current calling directory when calling a thor script - the script is processed through a Symlink.

So calling

```
say( "\n\t#{ Dir.pwd }\n\t" )
```

Returns the folder the script is hosted in - rather than the CLI directory I called the script from.

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it should work.

```
say( "\n\t#{ File.realpath(__FILE__) }\n\t" )
```